# How to wrap C++ VTK custom function for Python

Tags: python, c++, swig, vtk

Is there any place I can find a working example to wrap a C++ function (using VTK) to be used by
Python?

Searched and found this page
[mix VTK and SWIG Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898041/mix-vtk-and-swig-python)
but there is no compiling details, and this simple example on this page
https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/vtkusers/2002-October/013980.html

But for my system Ubuntu 16.04, vtk 8.2.0, Python 3.6.8, I could not make the example work.
I have to modify them to let the compiling done without error.

Details:
#============simple.cpp===================

```
// simple.c
//based on https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/vtkusers/2002-October/013980.html
#include "Python.h"
#include "vtkPythonUtil.h"
#include "vtkObject.h"
#include "vtkObjectBase.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "vtkRenderer.h"

extern "C" 
{
   static PyObject* simple_vtk_function(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);
}


static PyObject* simple_vtk_function(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
   PyObject *vtkpy;
   if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &vtkpy))
     return NULL;
   
   vtkObjectBase *obj = vtkPythonUtil::GetPointerFromObject(vtkpy,"PyObject");
   /* Do what you want to do here. */
   //printf("%s\n", obj->GetClassName());
   
   printf("inside module simple_vtk, function simple_vtk_function\n");
   
   Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
static char simple_docs[] =
   "simple( ): Any message you want to put here!!\n";

static PyMethodDef module_methods[] = 
{
    {
      "simple_vtk_function", (PyCFunction) simple_vtk_function, 
     METH_VARARGS, simple_docs
    },
    {NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef simple_vtk =
  {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "simple_vtk",/* name of module */
    "",/* module documentation, may be NULL */
    -1,
    module_methods
  };


PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_simple_vtk(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&simple_vtk);
}
```

#============setup.py===================

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import distutils.core as dc
module = dc.Extension('simple_vtk',
                      sources = ['simple.cpp'],
                      include_dirs=['/usr/local/include/vtk-8.2'],
                      libraries_dirs = ['/usr/local/include/vtk-8.2'],
                      #libraries=['vtkPythonUtil']
)
dc.setup(name = 'simple_vtk',
         version = '1.0',
         ext_modules = [module])
```

compile command

CFLAGS="-std=c++11" python setup.py build

and get this printing out

```
/home/jun/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/extension.py:131: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'libraries_dirs'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build
running build_ext
building 'simple_vtk' extension
gcc -pthread -B /home/jun/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c++11 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/vtk-8.2 -I/home/jun/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c simple.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/simple.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
simple.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* simple_vtk_function(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
simple.cpp:22:19: warning: unused variable ‘obj’ [-Wunused-variable]
    vtkObjectBase *obj = vtkPythonUtil::GetPointerFromObject(vtkpy,"PyObject");
                   ^
g++ -pthread -shared -B /home/jun/anaconda3/compiler_compat -L/home/jun/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/jun/anaconda3/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ -std=c++11 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/simple.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/simple_vtk.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

to test in python

```
>>> import simple_vtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/jun/project/play/swig/for_vtk_v2/simple_vtk.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN13vtkPythonUtil20GetPointerFromObjectEP7_objectPKc
```

The C++ function is so simple, it just to convert a  PyObject and convert to vtkObjectBase. I didn't even remove the simple print
printf("%s\n", obj->GetClassName());

But I could never make it work. I think it is a common need for people to wrap a custom C++ vtk function for Python, a little bit surpring there is almost no woring example on internet.
Could you please help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: I have never done this using anaconda,  but a few times using PyPi. First, you need to build VTK with VTK_WRAP_PYTHON and link to the library where vtkPythonUtil is defined.

Comment: Thanks @Jens Munk, I will try what you suggested and report the results.